# Test multiple decoupled input ports using OrderedDecoupledHWIOTester

Tags: chisel

Does `OrderedDecoupledHWIOTester` support testing a DUT that has two or more decoupled input ports?

For example, is there any way to express something like:

```scala
inputEvent(decoupledPort1.bits <- 10)
inputEvent(decoupledPort2.bits <- 11)
```

to create two series of values gated concurrently into these two ports?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  The *Ordered* part of *OrderedDecoupledHWIOTester* means that the input events are not concurrent. I think you may be able to implement this using the `chisel3.iotesters.AdvTester`.  But I don't see any good examples. I will see if I can create one.